# Error configuring multiples mongodb servers in Symfony 2.8

Tags: mongodb, symfony, session

I already have my app ( Symfony 2.8) hosted in Heroku. I have a mongoDB plugin to store session and it's working fine but when I try to add a replica server I face some problems. Replica is providaded by default for mongodb plugin. I mean

I am going to explain my environment and configuration:

**ENV**

I want to use this url ( it's which mongodb plugin provide me in Heroku)

```
MONGOLAB_URI = "mongodb://heroku_user:heroku_password@ds245975-a0.mlab.com:45975,ds245975-a1.mlab.com:45975/heroku_3b4l8zhl?replicaSet=rs-ds245975"
```

If I use this one is working:

```
MONGOLAB_URI = mongodb://heroku_user:heroku_password@ds245975-a0.mlab.com:45975/heroku_3b4l8zhl
```

**CONF**

In **parameters.php** I get this info:

```
$mongoLabUri = getenv('MONGOLAB_URI');
    $mongoLabUri = getenv('MONGOLAB_URI');
    if (false !== $mongoLabUri) {
        $matches = [];
        preg_match(
            '#mongodb://(?P<user>.*?):(?P<password>.*?)@(?P<server>.*)/(?P<database>[^?]*)#',
            $mongoLabUri,
            $matches
        );

        $container->setParameter('mongo_server', 'mongodb://'.$matches['user'].':'.$matches['password'].'@'.$matches['server']."/".$matches['database']);
        $container->setParameter('mongo_database', $matches['database']);
}
```

And in the configuration file, I configured the session handler to work with below parameters:

**config.yml**

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: %mongo_server%
            options: {}
    default_database: %mongo_database%
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true

services:
    session.handler.mongo:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MongoDbSessionHandler
        arguments: [@mongo, %mongo.session.options%]

    mongo.connection:
        class: MongoDoctrine\MongoDB\Connection
        factory_service: doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager
        factory_method: getConnection
        calls:
           - [initialize, []]
    mongo:
        class: Mongo
        factory_service: mongo.connection
        factory_method: getMongo

parameters:
    mongo.session.options:
        database: %mongo_database%
        collection: session
```

**Things that I tried**

- Configured the mongo_server with ?replicaSet=rs-ds245975
- Remove ?replicaSet=rs-ds245975
- I connect from mongo console to both server and it works.
- Modified symfony configuration:

  -https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/mongodb_session_storage.html

  -https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html

Anything is working. I face different problem when I try to set the replica. It seems that there are some misunderstood that right now I am not able to see.

Any help/tip is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I need to modified the configuration of doctrine_mongodb in this way:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: %mongo_server%
            options:
                connect: true
                replicaSet: true
                slaveOkay: true
    default_database: %mongo_database%
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

And now is working